# Can't save more than 10 object in localStorage

Tags: javascript

I have very specific problem. Can't save more than 10 object in localStorage.

To object key 10 javascript code works great but when 10th object saved in localStorage can't save 11th object.

11th object just overwriting 10th object.

Here is my code:

```js
// save in localStorage
ht.addEventListener(
  "click",
  function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    let nl = localStorage,
      keys = Object.keys(localStorage).sort(),
      mtch = false,
      ns = {
        link: f[i].link,
        source: f[i].pubDate + " - " + f[i].source,
        title: f[i].title,
        description: f[i].description,
      };
    //console.log(keys)
    if (nl.length > 0) {
      for (let n = 0; n < nl.length; ++n) {
        if (JSON.parse(nl[keys[n]]).link == f[i].link) {
          mtch = true;
        }
      }
      // if info is unique
      if (!mtch) {
        let key = parseInt(keys.pop()) + 1;
        console.log(key, "a");
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(ns));
      }
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem(0, JSON.stringify(ns));
    }
  },
  { passive: true }
);
```

Comment: Where i variable come from ? And f variable also ?

Comment: i and f variables are not the problem

Comment: this part of code not saving 11th object in localstorage: 
      if (!mtch) {
        let key = parseInt(keys.pop()) + 1;
        console.log(key, "a");
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(ns));
      }

Comment: What you want to achieve with that ? it makes no sense to me, you just take the last key in the local storage, parse to int and add one, but keys are string, you could have an app_data key for example. You need to use a single entry in the local storage and store an array

Comment: 11th object not saving in localStorage it overwrites 10th object after click on ht element

Comment: yeah it's expected you can't use localStorage like that, use a single key and store an array. You use getItem('myarray') to retrieve your array, add new values and put it back in the localStorage with setItem('myarray'). You will need to json encode/decode though

Comment: Like what? till 11th object keys and values saving normali like 0,1,2,3,... only then when object key in localstorage reach 10 11th object wich must saved right after 10th object overwrites 10th object.

Comment: Yeah it's expected because they are sorted, it's not a number but a string, they are sorted alphabetically, use an array instead

Comment: removed sort() function and still not working

Comment: it will never work, you need to rethink the whole thing, and use a single localStorage key, use an array and Json stringify it and store it in the localStorage

Comment: ok i will do like you said